# How to set table alias in select query

Tags: python, sql, peewee

By default, peewee assigns `t1`, `t2`, etc names to the tables
I'm trying to build some complex query in peewee, so I would like to alias table names.

Let's assume simple case: we have a table `<MyTable>`, how can I got something like

```
select foo.id from MyTable as foo;
```

What I've tried is setting `alias`, but it looks like it's a class method and it doesn't work:

```
MyTableModel.select().from_(MyTableModel.alias(), SomeOtherTable)  # << won't work
```

I found `AliasMap` class, which is set as default for `alias_map_class` class variable in the `QueryCompiler`. Also, there is `alias` method in `QueryCompiler`, but it is for [other](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.alias) purposes:

> The alias() method is used to create self-joins.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, have to dig into [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options-and-table-metadata) a little bit more:

```
class MyTable(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_alias = 'my_alias'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
car_model = Cars.as_entity().alias('car_type_query')
car_type_query = Cars.select(car_model.c.car_type_id)\
                .from_(car_model)\
                .where(car_model.c.id == car)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.